# friend request and friendship table, I have an idea is it OK?

Tags: java, mysql, server-side, java-server

I have my own server, that get from the client friend requests:
- case 1:
  user001 sends friend request to user002 
    1.   I create table called user001 in my server, with two colunms: friendID,status(accepted,blocked ect..)
and insert "user002" as a value of friendId column.
 
    2.and create another table named user002 and insert user001  as a value of friendId column.
so every user has his own table with list of his friends, is this good way, or there is another way...
 I choose this way, to make it easy to retrive friend list and another info. about a spicific friend.

Comment: So for 1Million user you tend to create 1M tables? that's awful.

Comment: if every question that apeare strage for u, u put -1 , this site rating will go down

Comment: No I will creat 2M tables not 1M, in the other side I will creat 1 table with 1M rows, with complex queries!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should only create one table, with columns UserId, friendId, Status. That way you can store all data in one table. To get user1's friends, filter on user1's UserId.

Comment: Ok, I did that but the problem is: when I look for friends of user001
the queery look for user001 in [uresID] colunm but it may be in the [friendID] colunm, and I cannot merge the results!!
I must make to SELECT statment, one look in the [USERID] and the other look In the [friendID]

Comment: Have you heard of `self join`? You can use that.

Comment: this is my last question in stackoverflow, thank for help. but I cannot ask when I a fraid of -1 that I will get

Comment: @Esmaeelibrahim I'm very sorry to hear that. The voting on SO can sometimes be a bit harsh, but the site is still a great resource to learn - as long as the question is kept on topic. And we all get a downvote now and then - that's part of how SO works. Move on and come back when you have a new question.